# Bug when adding a new row in mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, crud

I would like to insert a new row in mat-table with a button. I have written a function and when I click on it a new row is inserted, but I get the error `CalculatoryBookingsComponent.html:62 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'rows -> 0'` and only the first 5 cells are displayed. Do you know what it is and how I can fix the error?

My Work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Code:

// HTML

```
<button class="crud-status" type="submit" mat-raised-button (click)="addRow()">add</button>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;">
                <div formArrayName="rows" *ngIf="attributesWithFormControls.includes(column.attribute); else otherColumns"> // Line 62: This is the area where the error code points to
                  <span class="edit-cell" [formGroupName]="i">
                      <mat-form-field>
                        <label>
                          <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="column.attribute">
                        </label>
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <ng-template #otherColumns>
                  {{ column.object  !== null ? row[column.object][column.attribute] : row[column.attribute]  }}
                </ng-template>
              </td>
```

// TS

```
// ********** DATA TABLE ARRAYS **********//

  private beforeMonthsColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    { attribute: 'name', name: 'Erlöse / Kostenarten', object: null, disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false },
    { attribute: 'kagNumber', name: 'KAG', object: null, disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false }

  ];
  private monthColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    { attribute: '1', name: 'Jan', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false },
    { attribute: '2', name: 'Feb', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false },
    { attribute: '3', name: 'Mrz', object: 'values', disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false }
  ];
  private afterMonthsColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    { attribute: 'note', name: 'Anmerkung', object: null, disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: false },
    { attribute: 'assignment', name: 'zugeordnet? KAG', object: null, disabledRanges: false, disabledAssignment: true }
  ];

  // Merged arrays
  public displayedColumns: EditColumns[] = [
    ...this.beforeMonthsColumns,
    ...this.monthColumns,
    ...this.afterMonthsColumns
  ];

 addRow() {
    this.dataSource.data.push(this.columns[this.index++])
    this.table.renderRows()
  }

 const formRowsData = [];
              const nameFormArray = this.calcBookingsForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
              // build form array values for text fields in data table rows
              for (const formRowDataEntry of formRowsData) {
                const consolidatedValues = {};
                // Combine rows values into one object
                for (const d of formRowDataEntry) {
                  consolidatedValues[d.attr] = d.value;
                }
                // bind values of one row to a form control group
                const rowGroup = this.formBuilder.group(consolidatedValues);
                nameFormArray.push(rowGroup);
                rowGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((rowData) => {
                  console.log('Row data changed:', rowData);
                });
              }
              this.dataSource.data = rows;
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: one moment I put on my work

Comment: My work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5ugvw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html     If you click on the add button, then you see my problem

Comment: In console shows another error while rendering, at least, in that stackblitz.

Comment: i have now fixed the errors in the console and kept the example a bit simple. But I still don't see a new row in the table. See my updated work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You should sync your FormArray values with array in table DataSource:

```
ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    rows: this.formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()])
  }); 

  this.dataSource.data = this.myForm.get('rows').value;
}

addRow() {
  const newItem = this.initItemRows();
  this.formArr.push(newItem);

  this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.concat(newItem.value);
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-9caesn?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)**

Comment: I have now added some parameters to the model, interface and array. Unfortunately not every cell is filled when inserting a new row and I get the error ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'rows -> 0 -> kagNumber' in the console.

Do you have an approach how to solve the problem? My updateWork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-gldkqw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts